# Alternative to Globals Here?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, global

I'm making a code that allow the user to play Pontoon (21) against the Computer.

As part of this, I'm using a function that picks a random card for the Computer from a list called `deck` (which is 'shuffled' randomly every three rounds, so the card is taken from index `0` and it removed) and adds it to a list called `comp_cards`, that acts as the Computer's 'hand'.

Currently, I am using a global called `card` to store the card the function picks. However, I've heard that it's best not to use globals in general, so I was wondering whether there was any *simple* alternative.

This is the code that defines the function:

```
def comp_random_card():
    global card
    card = deck[0]
    deck.pop(0)
    comp_cards.append(card)
```

And this is the code that uses it:

```
input("Computer twisted and was dealt "+card)
        input("Computer: "+" ".join(comp_cards))
```

EDIT: when I pick the random card, I need to refer to it more than once. Also, I don't know what a 
class is (I'm kinda newish to Python).

Comment: There's always an alternative, but you haven't really shown enough of your code. Why can't you return the card from the function?

Comment: Create a class and store the state in attributes and make that function a method of that class.

Comment: Once you get the game working, considering posting to [CodeReivew.SE] for more thorough constructive criticism. (Make sure to read and follow their community guidelines.)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I edited my question to respond to them.

Answer (score 0):

How about returning it directly:

```
def comp_random_card():
  return deck.pop(0)
```

The above function uses the fact that `pop` returns the item besides deleting it.
Your variable is now nicely limited by the function's scope!

In your code you do not show the score of `deck` however which should also be somehow handled. You could make something like:

```
class Game(object):
    def __init__(self):
       self.deck = code_that_creates_deck()

    def round(self):
        computed_hand = comp_random_card()
        play_round()

    def comp_random_card(self):
        return self.deck.pop(0)
```